# Sql Reporting Services Parameter Question

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, reporting-services

I'm new with SQL Reporting Services 2008 and cannot find out how to do something that should be simple.

What I have is a single select parameter that is populated with a list of salesman from a query.  This works great.  And I have the dataset query responding to this parameter working well.  So my reports for a single salesman are working fine.

My problem is that I would also like to have an option that is ALL Salesman so that the manager can print out a complete list.

Any suggestions on how to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually UNION ALL a custom value to the top of my query with a special value that would indicate to my later query that it should not filter.

I usually use NULL, 0, or '%' for this.

Something like:

```
SELECT 0 [UserId], '(All Users)' [Username]
UNION ALL
SELECT
    [UserId],
    [Username]
FROM
    dbo.[Users]
```

And then, in the later query:

```
SELECT * FROM Data WHERE (UserID = @UserID OR @UserID = 0)
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked.  Hardest thing to get use to in reporting services is the fact that for a lot of things, there are not selections to do what you want, but rather like this, you sort of "trick" the system into doing what you want.  Not that this is really hard, just a very different way of thinking for me of late.

Answer (score 1):

Your sales person query probably looks like this:

```
SELECT SalesPersonName FROM SalesPerson ORDER BY SalesPersonName ASC
```

You should change it to this:

```
SELECT 1 as SortOrder, SalesPersonName FROM SalesPerson
UNION SELECT 0 as SortOrder, 'All' ORDER BY SortOrder, SalesPersonName
```

Now your query will return:

```
All
Adam
Barry
Steve
...
```

Now when you pull your data for the report you can do:

WHERE (SalesPersonName = @SalesPersonName OR @SalesPersonName='All')

And make sure you set the default to 'All' if that is what your manager wants.